# what is /d:VRI on logcat output

Tags: android, multi-touch

My app displays messages on logcat with the filter d:/GLES3JNI

I have set filter on logcat "GLES3JNI" and activated the setting show only selected application

And I see logs created by my app.

Now when I press a 3 points multitouch event the logcat displays a message:

D/VRI[my_app_activity]: FingersGesture gesture, start cancel motion

I don't know what this VRI is and how to disable it